# JDBC replacement: SQLNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

in my java project I switched from utf8 to utf8mb4. I dropped the database and than created a new one with utf8mb4.
I also changed the mysql-Configuration: my.ini with the input from https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4
The Changes now looks like this:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I checked over:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';

character_set_filesystem, binary
character_set_client, utf8
character_set_connection, utf8
character_set_results, utf8
character_set_system, utf8
collation_connection, utf8_general_ci
character_set_database, utf8mb4
character_set_server, utf8mb4
collation_database, utf8mb4_unicode_ci
collation_server, utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I tried adding - but mysql didn't started now - so i removed it:

```
character_set_client=utf8mb4
character_set_connection=utf8mb4
character_set_results=utf8mb4
```

Now I restarted the database.

Then I loaded the new driver to the project and replaced the old one with the newest. (-> now: mysql-connector-java-6.0.5-bin)
I also changed my java code to (because a driver error told me to do):
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

Afterwards i changed :

```
    String databaseUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB?useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=utf8mb4";

(because: SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported character encoding 'utf8mb4'
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError)
```

to:

```
    String databaseUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB?useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true";
```

With the new approach it throws:

```
    SQLException: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at auxiliary.InputCreater.saveFile(InputCreater.java:100)
    at auxiliary.InputCreater.searchnewfiles(InputCreater.java:54)
    at gui.EingabefensterController$3.handle(EingabefensterController.java:70)
    at gui.EingabefensterController$3.handle(EingabefensterController.java:1)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$343(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.checkNotNull(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.offer(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:325)
    at java.util.AbstractQueue.add(AbstractQueue.java:95)
    at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.add(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:312)
    at mysql.ConnectionPoolManager.initializeConnectionPool(ConnectionPoolManager.java:49)
    at mysql.ConnectionPoolManager.initialize(ConnectionPoolManager.java:43)
    at mysql.ConnectionPoolManager.<init>(ConnectionPoolManager.java:28)
    at mysql.CrawlerUpdate.<clinit>(CrawlerUpdate.java:18)
    ... 46 more
```

Why isn't there a connection? Before I made all of these changes everything worked fine.

Comment: AFAIK that property indicates the Java character set to use, not the MySQL character set. Also, please post the full stack trace of those ExceptionInInitializerErrors, as they usually include the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in a missing

```
&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

I found it out through varying the url.